# magento2 - tax amount gets difference of 0.01 for the products which have the same price

Tags: magento2, tax-rounding

I am using magento2.1.3. I am getting a difference of 0.01 in tax amounts for 2 different products but having the same price. For example I added  product1 with 1000 price. Added another Product2 with 1000 price and finished the checkout. Lookin at the order details page in the backend it shows 166.67 for product1 and 166.66 for product2 in the tax amount column. In the quote_item table also it is saved like this. Ideally it should be 166.67